# Fixing alignment in equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I wish to get a more typical alignment (I hope this obvious) than what I am getting with the following code:

```
\[                                                                                                                                                                           
 \hat\delta = \left \{                                                                                                                                                       
   \begin{array}{lr}                                                                                                                                                         
    \hat\delta(q_i, \epsilon) &= q_i \\                                                                                                                                      
    \hat\delta(q_i, ax) &= \hat\delta(\delta(q_i, a), x) : a\in\Sigma, x\in\Sigma^*                                                                                          
     \end{array}                                                                                                                                                             
   \right.                                                                                                                                                                   
\]
```

This produces:[image: Weird Alignment]

After seeing the above picture, I believe it is obvious that I wish to move the = sign and the q_i over to the left in the alignment. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Make your `{lr}` alignment `{ll}`, or else use the `align` environment of `amsmath`.

Comment: Thanks! That did it! What do both of those code segments do?

Comment: They define the alignment of the columns in your array: l = left, r = right

Comment: The introduction of `&` into the `array` environment are column delimiters.  Since you have one `&`, it means you have two columns.  The `{ll}` specifier to the environment means left-align the two columns.  The way you had it, the first column was left aligned, while the second was right-aligned.  The other alignment is a `c` for center-alignment.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the equals signs should be aligned, so a simple `cases` environment suffices. However, I add also the “aligned” version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
First attempt, like I would do it; there's
no need to align the equals signs:
\[
\hat\delta =
\begin{cases}
\hat\delta(q_i, \epsilon) = q_i, \\
\hat\delta(q_i, ax) = \hat\delta(\delta(q_i, a), x), & a\in\Sigma,\ x\in\Sigma^*
\end{cases}
\]
Second attempt, aligning the equals signs:
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\hat\delta =
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}ll@{}}
\hat\delta(q_i, \epsilon) &{}= q_i, \\
\hat\delta(q_i, ax) &{}= \hat\delta(\delta(q_i, a), x), & a\in\Sigma,\ x\in\Sigma^*
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \hat\delta
  = \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    \hat\delta(q_{i}, \epsilon)
      &= q_{i} \\
    \hat\delta(q_{i}, ax)
      &= \hat\delta(\delta(q_{i}, a),x)
         \qquad \text{for } a \in \Sigma, x \in \Sigma^{\ast}
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
or
\begin{equation*}
  \hat\delta
  = \left\{
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &\hat\delta(q_{i}, \epsilon)
      &&= q_{i} \\
    &\hat\delta(q_{i}, ax)
      &&= \hat\delta(\delta(q_{i}, a),x)
          \qquad \text{for } a \in \Sigma, x \in \Sigma^{\ast}
  \end{alignedat}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Using the `cases` or the `align*` environment would give a better spacind around the `=` sign. For the solution with `align*`, loading the [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package with `overload` option allows a simpler syntax:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[overload]{ empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}[left = {\hat\delta =\empheqlbrace}]
   \hat\delta(q_i, \epsilon) &= q_i \\
   \hat\delta(q_i, ax) &= \hat\delta(\delta(q_i, a), x) : a\in\Sigma, x\in\Sigma^*
\end{align*}

\[ \hat\delta =
   \begin{cases}
      \hat\delta(q_i, \epsilon)= q_i \\
      \hat\delta(q_i, ax)= \hat\delta(\delta(q_i, a), x) : a\in\Sigma, x\in\Sigma^*
   \end{cases} \]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: output]